# Check if __builtins__ is callable using list comprehension, avoiding errors with eval(print)

Tags: python, python-2.7, eval, built-in

I would like to check if those listed in `__builtins__` return `True` from `callable` (as a method for testing if they're a function or not).  I'm hoping to return a list of [those](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) functions in the Python documentation.  I realise additional items such as `AttributeError` return `True` for `callable`, that's fine.

The following returns a `SyntaxError` when I call it (due to `eval(print)`):

```
[callable(eval(x)) for x in dir(__builtins__)]
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

How can I test which of those in `__builtins__` are callable functions while sidestepping errors thrown from `eval(print)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more robust way of doing this would be to use `getattr`:

```
>>> [callable(getattr(__builtins__, attr)) for attr in dir(__builtins__)]
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `getattr` instead of `eval`:

```
builtins = map(lambda obj: getattr(__builtins__, obj), dir(__builtins__))
```

Then you can filter the results for callables:

```
filter(callable, builtins)
```

Note that could also use [inspect.getmembers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers). It even allows for an optional argument to filter the results:

```
inspect.getmembers(__builtins__, callable)
```